# Visual C++ 2010 slow at freeing array pointers

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

At the end of my application I simply call the following to clean up.

```
delete [] array1;
delete [] array2;
delete [] array3;
delete [] array4;
delete [] array5;
delete [] array6;
delete [] array7;
delete [] array8;
delete [] array9;
delete [] array10;
delete [] array11;
delete [] array12;
delete [] array13;
```

13 pointers to arrays on the heap. It takes an absolute **age** in debug mode...like 3-5 minutes, when it should be practically instantaneous. What gives?

Update: I assumed I was deleting an array of C-style structs (i.e. structs with only primitives and pointers) but two of the arrays had hash_maps in them which were taking the bulk of the time to clean up.

Comment: Have you considered using a two-dimensional or jagged array?

Comment: What happens in release mode?

Comment: When your process is exiting, you should not worry about freeing memory.  Any memory that's leaked is completely reclaimed when the process exits (under any sane OS).  Only worry about cleanup of resources which persist after the process terminates (for example, file persist, so write buffers need to be flushed).

Comment: Clearly 13 is an unlucky number here.  Don't write code like this.  Otherwise, bizarro problems like these are usually associated with heap corruption.  Use taskmgr.exe to look at the page fault delta for the process, in case virtual memory paging is trashing badly due to a lack of RAM.

Comment: Enough compilable code to allow someone to attempt reproduce the problem would be good here.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That is horrible advice. The reason is that the memory that was not free'ed on purpose ends up hiding actual memory leaks.

Comment: @Roger: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/05/10253268.aspx

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well, even gurus like Raymond Chen can be wrong. There were a few voices of sanity in that thread, like the comment from ulric.

Comment: @Roger: ulric's comment is far far worse.  Changing the shutdown behavior between debug and release?  Terrible idea, now you introduced a whole new class of bugs (failure to flush buffers) that disappear under a debug build.  And, as Raymond pointed out, now you have an order-of-destruction fiasco equivalent to the static initialization order fiasco.  And as other comments noted, processes do terminate abnormally at times, so relying on any behavior to occur at shutdown is foolish.  Driver code can run even after abnormal termination, but even there sudden loss of power is an issue.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oops. He did throw that in that at the end, didn't he. Sorry. Yes, it is a ridiculous idea. Ok, so there are even fewer voices of sanity in that thread than I first thought :)

Answer (score 3):

If the arrays hold objects with destructors, delete[] calls each destructor.

If the arrays are big, the objects may have to be swapped in from virtual memory before their destructors can be called.

Depending on your configuration, delete[] may be checking the boundary areas of the arrays to see if you have done any out-of-bounds writes.

In general, you should completely ignore execution time in debug mode, but I understand why you would wonder about it taking 3-5 minutes just to free your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could be happening.  Try halting the program while its being slow a few times and see what is on the stack in the debugger.

Recall that the destructor of whatever the element type is of array will be called once for each element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about performance then run your code in a profiler. You **can not** talk about performance without talking about profilers.